# Sort arraylist of objects containing epochs in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I've an arraylist of objects like `arrlist =[obj1, obj2,obj3]`, where each object contains `epochs` and an Integer i.e. `obj_i = {"1493275005401", 2} for all i` . I want to sort arraylist on the basis of epochs. Being a beginner in java, I don't know much how to do this.

Note: I did some googling, came up with `Collections.sort()` but I'm not sure how to tell sort to sort on a specific field of the object.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Does it change the sorted output if I consider `epoch`(TIME) as just `string` instead of `time.`?

Comment: Comparators are what you need here. https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework

Comment: reason for downvote?

Comment: @chandresh Lack of effort shown, presumably

Comment: @khelwood. Is the effort clear in the question now?

Comment: @chandresh Somewhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collections.sort` with a Comparator, consider you have this :

```
List<Item> arrlist = Arrays.asList(new Item("1493275005401", 2), new Item("14932", 5), 
    new Item("778888", 1));
```

If you want to sort using the first Item which is String you can use :

```
Collections.sort(arrlist, (o1, o2) -> {
    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
});
```

If you want to sort using the second Item which is and int you can use :

```
Collections.sort(arrlist, (o1, o2) -> {
    return o1.getId() - o2.getId();
});
```

Note : You can also sort your List with multiple itmes.

---

**Edit**

because epoch is an Integer you can convert it to BigInteger and compare your dates :

```
Collections.sort(arrlist, (o1, o2) -> {
    return new BigInteger(o1.getName()).compareTo(new BigInteger(o2.getName()));
});
```

Comment: new information, what did you mean @NewUser also the order will not change, or what did you mean?

Comment: i got it @NewUser thank you for the new information i appreciate it you can't add or remove your list

Comment: `List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("name");
asList.remove(0);` this will fail..

Comment: @YCF_L  Does it change the sorted output if I consider epoch as just string instead of time.?

Comment: @chandresh in my example i consider `1493275005401` like a string not a time

Comment: But it is `epoch` and hence time.

Comment: what did you mean by epoch? i don't get it @chandresh ?

Comment: ah ok, yes it work fine you can use it like it is @chandresh did you try it?

Comment: I tried it but it gives lexicographic ordering which is not the same as time ordering. I got this ordering {14932,1493275005401,778888}.

Comment: this is just an example @chandresh you have to use your real values of epoch?

Comment: I understand that. If we follow, epoch ordering, I should have got {14932,778888,1493275005401}(assume they are real values) which represents the time elapsed since Jan 1, 1970. This is where I was worried going through just string sort.

Comment: @chandresh you can use this `return new BigInteger(o1.getName()).compareTo(new BigInteger(o2.getName()));` in your comparator, i already edit my answer

Comment: @NewUser It's not an immutable list. Just a fixed-size list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<T>)` to do this. You just need to specify a `Comparator` that uses the `epoch` component of your datatype.

Lets assume your type looks like this (the epoch seems to be a String):

```
class Container {
  String epoch;
  Integer i;
  Container(String e, Integer ii){
    epoch = e;
    i = ii;
  }
}
```

Then you can create a Comparator that compares the numerical (!) value of the epoch String:

```
class ContComparator implements Comparator<Container> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Container o1, Container o2) {
    final Long epoch2 = Long.valueOf(o2.epoch);
    final Long epoch1 = Long.valueOf(o1.epoch);
    return epoch1.compareTo(epoch2);
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
List<Container> arrlist = ... ;
Collections.sort(arrlist, new ContComparator());
```

Comment: any idea how to get back the epoch representation from string one and then sort based on epoch (time)?

Answer (score 0):

Try Comparators:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(obj -> Long.parseLong(obj.getEpoch())));
```

This is the newer syntax and Comparator API introduced with Java 8. The `comparing` method takes a function as a parameter that will extract the relevant attributes from the elements in the list.

If you read the JavaDoc of the `comparing` methods of Comparator you will find more information on how to modify the sorting further.

For a better understanding on what is happening:

```
list.sort(new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return Long.parseLong(o1.getEpoch().toMillis()) - Long.parseLong(o2.getEpoch().toMillis());
    }
})
```

Comment: The ``epoch`` field seems to be a ``String``, so you need a conversion first.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting by epoch time, we can do this
`anyList.sort(Comparator.comparing(o.getEpoch()))`